# Scrape page on download site to extract specific URLs

Tags: php, web-scraping

On a download site, I want to scrape all the URLs for the mirror sites. I am using PHP.

For example, on this page:

```
http://drivers.softpedia.com/progDownload/Gigabyte-GA-P55A-UD3-rev-10-Intel-SATA-RAID-Preinstall-Driver-9501037-Download-99091.html
```

I want to extract the following URLs:

```
http://drivers.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=99091&t=0&i=1
http://drivers.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php?p=99091&t=0&i=2
```

Comment: Wut? Where in the above link are those two mirror links referenced? Please clarify.

Comment: @Pekka I have rewritten it, just waiting for edit to be approved. The mirror URLs are on the first URL.

Comment: And that site has fantastically semantic HTML, which really makes this job easy... [/sarcasm]

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
(http:\/\/drivers\.softpedia\.com\/dyn-postdownload\.php\?p=\d+&t=\d+&i=\d+)
```

Comment: @Thoman well, some of those escapes are just for the `/`'s enclosing the regular expression. Using an alternate character like `|` or `%` often makes it a bit more readable: `preg_match_all("%http://drivers\.softpedia\.com/dyn-postdownload\.php\?p=\d+&t=\d+&i=\d+%", $buffer, $matches);`

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear where you got the "t" and "i" parameters from the source url, it only contains the id (p). The below should do for retrieving that last group of digits.

```
%(\d+)\.html$%
```